# repaint method is doing nothing once called

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, java-2d

I am trying to understand how `repaint` and `paintComponents` work in Java Swing, and wondering why this program only display "hello" when it's executed.

```
class MyLabel extends JLabel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyLabel(){
        System.out.println("hello");
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        System.out.println("painting");
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         MyLabel lbl = new MyLabel();
}
```

Comment: I don't see `hello` in your code at all.

Comment: Hello get print from the MyLabel constructor

Comment: `public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);` **should be** `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);`  (no plural).

Comment: @AndrewThompson So this _is_ the answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It works now. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) { 
  super.paintComponents(g);
```

Should be:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
  super.paintComponent(g);
```

(no plural).

This way:

- The paint chain is not broken.
- The `painting` string will appear (as many times as the API feels necessary to paint the component).

Comment: Thanks, it works. but `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponents(g); }` still works as well (second one is only in plural). Can you explain this ?

Comment: *"Can you explain this ?"*  I would not try.  Use the (right) methods as they are intended to be used and things work flawlessly.  The behavior of anything else is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have just create an instance of the MyLabel. Therefore your sout in the constructor get called and prints hello.
Normally in swing repaint() method get trigger either by system event or a app-event. But since you have just create an instance and not placing it anywhere no event get triggered.
you can read up on [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)